# When calling [self.tableView reloadData]; i get stuck in a loop

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, loops, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController class which when i call  [self.tableView reloadData]; it gets stuck in a loop? Is there a way to break the loop?

The UITableViewController calls another class which then calls a method in the UITableViewController{

```
-(void)callToConfirm
{
[arrMain removeAllObjects];
[arrMain addObject:[searchText capitalizedString]];
[self.tableView reloadData];
NSLog(@"Symbol Exists!");
}
```

Comment: with crystal ball i can only advise you to make sure you are not returning something wrong inside numberOfChildrenOfItem, child ofItem and other delegate methods, double check them and your data source structure.

Comment: I have added some more information.

Comment: to accept an answer click the semi clear checkmark next to the question.  This allows others to know what the appropriate answer is so that others can benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post the backtrace of the loop.   Without more information, it is impossible to say, but there are two scenarios that can lead to this:

1. You are calling `reloadData` while filling the table view.  If you have any kind of lazy loading mechanism and that mechanism is triggered while loading the table view *and* it calls `reloadData`, then... *boom*.
2. Your data load is telling the table view that it is invalidated and needs to reload during the next pass through the run loop.   Effectively looks like an infinite loop.